# How can I make loop instead of switch statement?

Tags: c#, loops

How can I write this shorter? For each case I have to write this and then It is too long because there are 48 numbers so I need 48 cases. Is there a way to make a loop?

```
switch (ballBounce.ToString())
        {
            case "1":
                if (ballBounce == n0)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = number.ToString();                        
                }
                break;

            case "2":
                if (ballBounce == n1)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = number.ToString();
                }
                break;

            case "3":
                if (ballBounce == n2)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = number.ToString();
                }
                break; ...
```

Comment: You obviously took the wrong way. But your code is too short to understand what it does. But from that I can say n0, n1, n2 should be an array.

Comment: You just need to pair `ballBounce` with `nX`. Sounds like you need a `Dictionary<int, int>`, then simply: `if (ballBounce == dictionary[ballBounce]) textBox1.Text = number.ToString()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop is useless in this case.
You can use dictionary.

```
private Dictinoary<string, string> cases = new Dictionary<string, string> {
  {"1", "one"},
  {"2", "two"},
  // ...
};

// in some method
string text;
if (cases.TryGetValue(ballBounce.ToString(), out text)){
   this.textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

If you want something smarter than simple value, you can have functions in the dictionary.

```
private Dictinoary<string, Func<string>> cases = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>> {
  {"1", () => "one"},
  {"2", () =>
    {
      if (DateTime.Now.Seconds % 2 == 0) { return "A"; }
      else { return "B"; }
    }},
  // ...
};

// in some method
Func<string> textProvider;
if (cases.TryGetValue(ballBounce.ToString(), out textProvider)){
   this.textBox1.Text = textProvider();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your ToString()'s, I'm assuming that ballBounce is an int.

```
if (ballBounce <= 48 && ballBounce > 0)
{
    textBox1.Text = ballBounce.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you use `if` with `case`?
you don't need to check twice.
also if this is the code for every case

```
textBox1.Text = number.ToString();
```

then you don't need `switch` or `if`
jsut write `textBox1.Text = number.ToString();` and you are good to go.
also if you have some cases ony you can do it that way:

```
switch (ballBounce.ToString())
{
    case "1":
    case "2":
    case"3":
    //....
     textBox1.Text = number.ToString();
 }
```